# On Selenium WebDriver how to get Text from title Tag inside of a text tag

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

On Selenium Webdriver, how I can retrieve text from a title tag inside of a text tag & print?

I need to extract the text Open

HTML code are as follow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHoRD.jpg)

I get 2 results, using the following xpath:

```
//div[@class='visual visual-card allow-deferred-rendering']//*[contains(text(),'Open')]
```

I have tried the following, but no luck

```
//div[@class='visual visual-card allow-deferred-rendering']//tspan[contains(text(),'Open')]

//div[@class='visual visual-card allow-deferred-rendering']//title[contains(text(),'Open')]
```

What might the xpath that returns 1 unique identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see in the pic that there are two elements with this xpath.
And the one you want is first one.
So, what you can do is:

(Your xpath)[required number element]

```
(//div[@class='visual visual-card allow-deferred-rendering']//title[contains(text(),'Open')])[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to XPath to select only `tspan` elements, hence filtering out the `title` element which also contains text "Open":

```
//div[@class='visual visual-card allow-deferred-rendering']//tspan[contains(text(),'Open')]
```

Comment: Tried the same but no luck

Comment: Not sure what was the problem? Still getting two results using the XPath above?